# How to make ion-scroll fit or wrap all the content inside it?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have the following  but it isn't letting me scroll through the whole list of my items. When I add a height to ` it lets me scroll depending of this height but this isn't correct for lists that can vary in size.

Is there any clean way to (without using style="height: ..." in the HTML) to make scroll fit/wrap it's content?

```
<ion-content>
     //more html elements here...
     <ion-scroll>
            <div class="list">
              <ul>
                <li class="item" ng-repeat="doctor in doctors">

                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
     </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>
```

Link to demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/e13756f7b285

As you can see in demo last item isn't showed and I want a static header at the top and the ion-scroll below.

Comment: why are you using <ion-scroll> when <ion-content> let you scroll . ??

Comment: @mudasserajaz, because this is already inside an   <ion-content>

Comment: i mean to say why are you adding <ion-scroll>? what benefit it is giving to you? even if you do not add this, still you will be able to scroll. You should put working demo of your code here play.ionic.io , so we can understand and solve problem.

Comment: @mudasserajaz added demo thanks

Comment: I have added answer and described proper way to make custom header and set content according to them, in which you will not have to use `<ion-scroll>`

Comment: Let me know if answer helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/55da08c5a9b5

Headers should not be kept inside `<ion-content>`, even if you are using custom header.Put it below `<ion-view>`. And never override ionic built in classes, as you were doing with `.header`, it is built in class from ionic. So make two custom classes, one to define header :

```
.my-custom-header{
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

And other to add to `<ion-content>`, so content know from where to start. As your header height is `100px`, so content will start from `100px`.

```
.has-custom-header{
  top:100px;
}
```

Now you do not need `<ion-scroll>` as you can use default scroll of content.

```
<ion-view>
<div class="my-custom-header">
      STATIC HEADER
</div>
<ion-content class="has-custom-header">
```